# serializing resource modification in Jersey

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, jersey

we use Tomcat7 as servlet container, Jersey 2.0 as REST framework, and MongoDB 3.2 as backend storage.

in our webapp design we have some resources for which we have POST requests to generate "downlevel" resources (dependent/related on them), whose creation can take some time, about 5..10 seconds. Sometimes, a repeated POST request can be sent from the client side which may cause generation of duplicate dependent resource.

the question is, can these operations be synchronized/serialized in some way, using facilities provided by Jersey itself (some its annotations, may be) ? I mean, that synchronization unit should be an uplevel resource, identified by its ID - not a synchronized region of code. So that same code modifying different resources could still be executed in parallel, but code attempting to modify a resource already undergoing modifications should block and wait for previous modification to complete.